# How to include Duo Authentication to Django UI after Windows Authentication

Tags: python, django, security, two-factor-authentication, django-two-factor-auth

i have a code which performs uploading of file to certain destination, and i have already include windows authentication as first phase of authentication and wanted to include Duo Security as second authentication.

So i referred few of the git and other platforms regarding duo security and edited my settings.py and Urls.py as below

**Settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'duo_auth',
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    'duo_auth.middleware.DuoAuthMiddleware',
]
DUO_CONFIG = {
    'DEFAULT': {
        'HOST': '<api-host-url>',
        'IKEY': '<integration_key>',
        'AKEY': '<app_secret_key>',
        'SKEY': '<secret_key>',
        'FIRST_STAGE_BACKENDS': [
            'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
        ]
    }
}
```

and URLS.py as

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('duo/',  include('duo_auth.urls')),
    path('', views.home,name='home'),
    path('create', views.create,name='create'),
    path('files', views.files,name='files'),
]+static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

and installed `django-duo-auth` and is successfully installed, i migrated the change and ran server, restarted app. But this is throwing me **error 500**.

So i really don know whether any change other than this is required or anything is to be added or removed. i didn't find any relative paper or article which i can read and solve this issue.

So this is the error obtained
[image: Error]

It says "THERE IS A PROBLEM WITH RESOURCE YOU ARE LOOKING FOR AND CANNOT BE DISPLAYED "

Comment: Can you include the error and the traceback?

Comment: Sure @Matt , i will include it now